# Use archive table to delete a product in a "daily sales database"

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a database for a daily sales report, so I can see how many product I sold on a specific day. For example:

16/01/2021 -> 50 apples were sold
16/01/2021 -> 30 lemons were sold
17/01/2021 -> 46 apples were sold
17/01/2021 -> 34 lemons were sold

I have these tables:

`products`

- id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
- name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
- price FLOAT NOT NULL
- Other stuff

`sales`

- saledate DATE,
- product_id INT,
- quantity INT,
- PRIMARY KEY (saledate, product_id),
- FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products(id),

It looks to works correctly. Now I have to give the option to delete a product. Obviously the "history" of the product has to remain. For example, if I delete "apple" from product table, I still need to know that "16/01/2021 -> 50 apples were sold".

I know there are two ways to do that: soft delete or use an archive table. With soft delete I can add a flag "is_deleted" to my "products" table, but in this way:

1. The "products" table will be heavy and slow with the passing years beacuse there could be many many products in the table
2. I will need to add the WHERE clause in my queries

So I thought to use an archive table, where i will move the product from the "products" table to the archive table (from now I will call it "archived_products" table). Here are the problems

1. **If I move a product from "products" table to "archived_products" table, the FOREIGN KEY in the "sales" table will be still linked to the "products" table**.
2. **Is it possible to restore the product from "archived_products" table to "products"? (obivisuly it need to keep it's old id on "products" table**

If you need, I can to provide an example for the 1. point

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Why did you tag this with "normalization"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How many `Products` do you consider a *lot*?...What do you define *slow* as? A correctly architected schema should be able to handle a `Products` table with 100s of **billions** of rows, even on *modest* hardware. (I've managed similar tables with 10s of billions of rows, that were quite performant, e.g. could query any specific product in 0 seconds.) Unless you plan to scale to support "big data" (single tables with 10s+ of terabytes of data), I wouldn't recommend being concerned with archiving your `Products` table.

Regardless these are your options (in order of recommendation):

1. Go the soft delete route and add a flag field to manage deleted `Products`.
2. Archive the `Products` and their correlating `Sales` to maintain referential integrity. This will cause additional management work and require two archive tables.
3. Alter your **foreign key constraint** to allow orphaned records. This will result in broken referential integrity.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. `A correctly architected schema should be able to handle a Products table with 100s of billions of rows` ok, I will use a flag. Thank you!

Comment: @secon25 No problem! I think it's the best route in terms of database design. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Don't delete Data.

Add a column  `active` int.

So you only select data for new purchases which has `active` = 1

If you don't need a product anymore, simple set `active` to 0.

To check the historical data, you don't need to check the new lolumn

Comment: I don't want to delete data, I want to move them in an archive table, I don't want to use a flag (I explained the reason in my post).  Sorry if I have been unclear

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could also archive the sales of a deleted product, so that the foreign key in the sales archive references the archived product and there's no more row in the actual sales table referencing the archived product. That however dramatically complicates queries that should run over actual and archived data.

Now for the big **but** (single t ;)): I'd recommend you go the soft delete route. Your assumptions on the impact of this are probably wrong or easily solvable:

- If you properly index the table including the "is deleted" flag, it most likely isn't going to be slow at all. Don't make complicated and unnecessary premature optimizations. They bear more harm than benefit.
- To avoid having to a add another predicate to the `WHERE` clause every time you query the products, when you actually only want the non deleted products, create a view with such a filter and query against that instead of the table directly. You can probably even make it updatable and ignore the actual table completely most of the time even in DML (though, ad hoc, I don't know how good MySQL supports updatable views, you need to research on that).

Answer (score 0):

**You should use a flag.**  It doesn't break the FK relationship to your `Sales` data and doesn't impose a huge overhead.

Before you fight it and say again "I don't want to use a flag", let's review what happens when you delete a row in most relational(ish) database management systems:

1. The row is marked as deleted

The space that row occupies is not utilized again until:

1. An insert or update operation requires it
2. The underlying table/heap is rebuilt

You're using an auto-incrementing value as a primary key, so the chances of that page actually storing additional active rows without a rebuild is practically nil.  So if you do "delete" the rows and move them into an audit table, this is what will happen:

1. Your delete operations are more complex
2. You are using more space than you would if you just marked the record `IsDeleted = 1`

With periodic maintenance, you could shrink the total number of pages, but even that might not provide any benefit beyond freeing up space, depending on how you query the `Product` table.  If you are always searching for 1 `Product` at a time, you will always read the B-Tree + 1 page no matter what.  If you are searching for multiple `Products`, you may read more pages than you would if the deleted rows were physically removed, but unless you're deleting **A LOT** of records, you're not going to see a noticeable increase.

**TLDR; use a flag**

Comment: I suggest that the flag should be called `no_longer_sold`.

Comment: @RickJames `IsAvailable`?